# How to change the app route path if a page (walkthrough) has been view once

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5, ion-slides, walkthrough, app-router

I have app walkthrough / intro built using ion-slides which is loaded as the default page in app.routing.module.ts .

```
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'walkthrough',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },{
    path: 'walkthrough',
    loadChildren: () => import('./walkthrough/walkthrough.module').then(m => m.WalkthroughPageModule)
  }
```

I only want to show this the first time the app is launched, so my question is how do I configure the app-route in the app-routing module to set the opening page just once?
I read the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides) and could not find a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone in a  similar situation you can add conditionals / user logic using angular route gaurds. In the Walkthrough.ts module I set the value to storage:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    // save key to mark the walkthrough as visited so the next time the user vistis the app, he would be redirected to log in
    Storage.set({
      key: 'visitedWalkthrough',
      value: 'true'
    });
  }
```

In a walkthrough.gaurd.ts I check for same value and change the route based on same:

```
const { Storage } = Plugins;

@Injectable()
export class WalkthroughGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  async canActivate(): Promise<boolean> {
    const { value } = await Storage.get({ key: 'visitedWalkthrough' });

    if (value === 'true') {
      // this is a returning user, don't show him the walkthrough
      this.router.navigate(['auth']);
      return false;

    } else return true;
  }
}
```

Good tutorial [here](https://codeburst.io/understanding-angular-guards-347b452e1892) :